# Asymptotics. Why can I use integral?

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

Given: 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n (i^\alpha) \ln^{\beta} (i) \approx \frac{n^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1} \ln^{\beta} n, \alpha > -1, n \rightarrow \infty$$
Task: prove the approximation

I know it may be proved using integral, but I can't figure out why.

The function in the sum is not monotonic. Why is it right to use integral?

Comment: The function is "eventually monotonic". There is an $i_0$ (depending on $\alpha$ and $\beta$) that the function is monotonic for $x > i_0$.